# Request 'GET' - Django CRUD conditional

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-templates, psycopg2

I'm trying to make a query on my DB, in Django, but so far I'm not getting any results, I'm kind of confused on this one.

Say `proyecto` is a kind of document I need to query, then I have this on models:

```
class Proyecto(models.Model):
    id_proyecto = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) #integer NOT NULL, CLAVE PRIMARIA
    nombre_proyecto = models.TextField(null=True) #text,
    existente = models.BooleanField()
```

Here, `existente` is a checkmark I have on my template, so, if this checkmark is active, then bring whatever document are you specifying into `nombre_proyecto` charfield.

forms.py:

```
class ProyectoForm(forms.Form):
    nombre_proyecto = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
    existente = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    def clean(self):
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Then, views.py:

```
def proyecto_view(request):
alerta=""
#existente = request.GET['existente']
#if existente is not None and existente != '':
if request.method == "POST":
    form = ProyectoForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        name =form.cleaned_data['nombre_proyecto'] #hay que verificar si el proyecto ya existe
        if Proyecto.objects.count() > 0:
            alerta="ya existe el proyecto"
            formProy = 1
            ctx ={'alerta':alerta, 'formProy':formProy}
            return render_to_response('scppp/inicial.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            if Proyecto.objects.count() == 0:
                id_proyecto=1
            else:
                id_proyecto=Proyecto.objects.all().aggregate(Max('id_proyecto'))['id_proyecto__max']+1
            nombre_proyecto = name

    else:
        if Proyecto.objects.count() < 0:
            alerta = "Introduzca un nombre de proyecto"
            formProy = 1
        else:
            alerta = "data erronea"
            formProy = 1
            ctx = {'alerta':alerta, 'formProy':formProy}
            return render_to_response('scppp/inicial.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
if request.method == "GET" and 'existente' in request.GET: //This is the method
    existente = request.GET['existente']
    if existente is not None and existente != '':
        Proyecto.objects.filter(nombre_proyecto=name)
        return render_to_response('scppp/pozo.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

On my template, this is how I have the checkmark `existente`:

```
<tr><td>
                    <span class="Sub-Titulo-Aplicacion">Proyecto: </span>
                    <input class="check-style" type="checkbox" name="tipo" value="checkbox" >Nuevo</input>
                  </td></tr>
                  <tr><td>
                    <input class="check-style" type="checkbox" name="existente" value="existente" >Existente</input>
                  </td></tr>
```

The checkmark "works" in an HTML point of view, but it's actually doing nothing... I don't know if I should declare something on my template or not, there are plenty of ways and I feel confused.

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "bring whatever document are you specifying into nombre_proyecto charfield." And note that if the form is valid but there are no Proyecto objects in the database, the view does not return any kind of response.

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes they do exist, I mean Proyecto is a table, a document in the db, it's like a SELECT * FROM proyecto; It should return something... I think there is some error with the checkmark, on controller or template.

Comment: Well, not really "SELECT *" it's more like SELECT * FROM proyecto WHERE nombre_proyecto 'name';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some obvious bug in your code:

```
if Proyecto.objects.count() < 0:
```

**count** means *an act of determining the total number of something.* and total number of something can not be less than zero.

So your code is logically wrong. this bug also affect these lines:

```
    if Proyecto.objects.count() > 0:
        alerta="ya existe el proyecto"
        formProy = 1
        ctx ={'alerta':alerta, 'formProy':formProy}
        return render_to_response('scppp/inicial.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        if Proyecto.objects.count() == 0:
            id_proyecto=1
        else:
            id_proyecto=Proyecto.objects.all().aggregate(Max('id_proyecto'))['id_proyecto__max']+1
        nombre_proyecto = name
```

Executation never reachs to else statement.

Also in your ** GET request ** processing in views there is another mistake.

```
if existente is not None and existente != '':
    Proyecto.objects.filter(nombre_proyecto=name)
    return render_to_response('scppp/pozo.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

you didn't use selected **Proyecto** instance from database. You should pass them to your template. Also you didn't declared ctx in this scope. (You just did it in **POST request** handling and a request can not be both of POST and GET).

```
if existente is not None and existente != '':
    projects = Proyecto.objects.filter(nombre_proyecto=name)
    ctx = {"projects" : projects}
    return render_to_response('scppp/pozo.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and also in your *scppp/pozo.html* you must have something like this to show them and use **projects**:

```
<table>
    {% for project in projects %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{project.id_proyecto}}</td>
        <td>{{project.nombre_proyecto}}</td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Ya, I think is a little messy, but all these lines work except the GET request, maybe I should refactor that conditional.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is in the template

Comment: Hi, I'm doing some refactoring I'll write back, sorry for the delay

Comment: Ya, the proyecto reference is on the template, I'm still refactoring

Comment: Ok, I have a better idea now, I'll open a new question, thank you!